# How could I improve the performance of this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider that you have a MySQL table named “user” with millions of rows that have the following structure, and doesn't have any index.

```
TABLE:  user_id (PK) email name signup_date
```

We want to execute the following query:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user
WHERE email=’email@bolidea.com’ AND name=’Olivier Cabanes’
```

1. How does MySQL handle that query in term of speed?
2. How can you improve the performance of that query?

Comment: Would "by adding an index" be too glib?

Answer (score 1):

you need an index on email and name, otherwise it will need to go thru every single line of the table and will be very slow...

Comment: Actually, under most circumstances, an index on either email or name would work.  These are pretty unique in identifying individuals.  You might end up pulling in 2 or 3 pages for the scan, but the performance would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put an index on *either* email or name. No need for an index on both, since both are basically unique on their own